# OOP in Python for big project. Import and structure issue

Tags: python, oop

I want to develop a big project.  Normally in Java, we can define several packages, inherit classes and etc.

In python, it seems complex. Assume this structure:

```
workspace
    package1
         AbsClass11
         class11 extended from  AbsClass11
         class12 extended from  AbsClass11
    class0
```

To import a class I have to write:

```
from package1.class11 import class11
class11()
```

Is there any easy way to import all classes automatically?

The following command won't work and we should use `class11.class11()` which is not an easy way.

```
from package1 import *
```

I found a tricky method but I want a good way.

```
#file __init__.py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
import importlib
for pack in __all__:
    globals().update(importlib.import_module('combiner.'+pack).__dict__)
```

Comment: yes, packages and modules, very well explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0

Comment: Don't do that if you fancy your mental health. And you don't have to have one module per class, this is Python not Java.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I want to make it easy to read and develop.

Comment: @Ali yes, and that's why I'm telling you not to do that. I can __garantee__ (from experience) that it's the worst possible "good idea" and makes for unreadable and unmaintainable code. Using package's `__init__.py` as a facade for (some of the) names defined in submodules as shown in Joe Habel's answer is fine (and a common pattern), but trying to automagically import all names from all submodules is really a terrible antipattern. When reading / debugging code, you __WANT__ to know __clearly__ and __exactly__ which names are imported and __where__ they are imported from. Been here, done that..

Comment: and FWIW, __never__ use wildcard imports  ("from xxx import *") in production code either, for the very same reasons.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an `__init__.py` module in your package to make this easier. You can read more about package structuring [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Assuming your current, structure, you would add the `__init__.py` module as such

```
workspace
    package1
         __init__.py
         AbsClass11
         class11 extended from  AbsClass11
         class12 extended from  AbsClass11
    class0
```

assuming that `AbsClass11`, `class11`, and `class12` are all modules themselves. Then the contents of the `__init__.py` module would look as such

```
from .AbsClass11 import AbsClass11
from .class11 import class11
from .class12 import class12
```

The purpose of the `__init__.py` module, is that when you import the package, the `__init__.py` module is executed. So now calling `from package1 import class11` would refer to the class and not the module, so the following

```
from package1 import class11
class11()
```

would now work.

`from package1 import *` would now also import `AbsClass11`, `class11`, and `class12`.

### Edit

From your comments, it looks as if you're looking for IDE functionality instead of actual Python code functionality. If you're looking for the IDE to automatically detect and include the import statement at the top of your module, like [Eclipse does](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-auto-import-all-java-classes-in-eclipse/), there's some Python IDEs that offer similar behavior.

Visual Studio Code has [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brainfit.vscode-importmagic) that does that, it appears [so does Atom](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/atom-python-import-magic), and [PyCharm offers this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html) out of the box.

And some small notes that might also be helpful, while having individual modules for each class is acceptable, you're not bound to that standard as you would be in Java, so it would be perfectly fine, and perhaps even more easy to maintain and navigate, the `AbsClass11`, `class11`, and `class12` all lived in the same module, instead of in a package. I'd recommend checking out [this guide](https://realpython.com/oop-in-python-vs-java/) if you're comfortable in the Java OOP style to understand what's not going to carry over as well from a Java style to Python style.

Comment: Thanks but i want an automatic way to do that. I don't want to include it explicitly

Comment: Python was designed around doing such tasks explicitly though. Literally from the second line of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "Explicit is better than implicit." What you're going to end up doing by trying to force in implicit importing like this is pollute the namespace. You can do it, but if you want to develop a big project like you said, you're going to make things very hard to maintain and debug when you run into a naming conflict.

Comment: I want to make it easy to add any submodule from others that's why I want to make it easy as possible

Comment: I think what you're looking for is behavior that's bound to the IDE more than that of the code that you're writing. I edited my answer to include some IDEs that provide automatically detecting and including the import statements for you.

Comment: My main problem is that I should write: from package1.class11 import class11 or if i want to instantiate it directly package1.class11.class11() it doesn't look pretty